# Fitness function example

Tags: optimization

I promised my son that I will understand myself and then explain him particle swarm optimization (PSO) with flock of birds or school of fish as an example.

Every tutorial on the web starts with animals for the motivation but none uses a fitness function that connects with animals.

Could you please give me a fitness function that realistically mimics the animal world with reasonable interpretation? Does fitness function give the error between swarm's current position and target position? If we know the target position,  isn't it the solution itself?